# Help with USB wireless network

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, usb

I've problem with my USB Network Reciever Belkin. I can't get it to work. I've cd with drivers, are they only for Windows? If I start Ubuntu and try to click `install.exe` doesn't work. I'm getting message like:

```
Archive: /media/F7D4101v1/setup.exe  Zip file size: 4911104 bytes, number of entries: 29824
     [/media/F7D4101v1/setup.exe]:
      Zipfile is disk 34294 of a multi-disk archive, and this is not the disk on
      which the central zipfile directory begins (disk 3569).
```

I'm new to linux, looks nice and all, but I can't to connect to my wireless network which make it usless. Btw, everything works fine on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the ndiswrapper to install the drivers. I recently had the same problem with a netgear wireless usb.

Also, .exe files are for windows so thats not gonna work out with linux, that's what the ndiswrapper is for.

I'm actually in the middle of repairing my Ubuntu partition at the moment so I don't have access to exact steps to take, but to get ya started, google ndiswrapper and download the tar. Then download the drivers for your card (if you can).

I'll add some more steps needed to get set up as soon as I can.

Comment: You may want to clarify that ndiswrapper is for attempting to use Windows drivers on a Linux-based operating system (it is not for running Windows `.exe` files in general).

Answer (score -1):

Unless you use a VM or software like [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/), `.exe` files are for Windows **only**.

The Drivers CD is for Windows.  If you want to get your network receiver to work, you will have to install the Drivers for Linux Specifically.

The first way is to install the drivers through Additional Drivers.

1. Plug In your Network Receiver.
2. Search for "jocky" in the dash and choose "Additional Drivers".
3. Find your Network Receiver from there and click "Activate".

If your Network Receiver is not listed, go to the [ndswrapper wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?joomla/index.php) to find your model and Install the Drivers.

EDIT: Read [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SetupNdiswrapperHowto?action=show) to install ndswrapper.  Posted essential contents here.

> 1. First, download the ndiswrapper1.5.tar.gz file from here to your $HOME directory.
> 2. Get yourself in a root shell by running  `sudo -s` followed by your user's password.
> 3. Now before we attempt to build the source, let's make sure we have the required tools to make it work. The following command should get
>      us everything we need.
>
>    `apt-get install debhelper build-essential fakeroot linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
> 4. Untar the ndiswrapper1.5.tar.gz file to your /usr/src directory. NOTE: the location where you untar the source doesn't
>      really matter, but the rest of these instructions will assume
>      /usr/src.
>
>    `cd /usr/src`
>
>    `tar xvzf ~/ndiswrapper1.5.tar.gz`
> 5. By default, the rules file that is responsible for specifying Debian packaging parameters specifies an install directory different
>      from where Ubuntu keeps the same module. I adjusted my rules file to
>      install in the proper place like so
>
>    `cd /usr/src/ndiswrapper1.5`
>
>    `sed -e "s/misc/kernel\/drivers\/net\/ndiswrapper/g" debian/rules > debian/temp`
>
>    `mv debian/temp debian/rules`
> 6. Enter the source directory and issue the make deb command.
>
>    `cd /usr/src/ndiswrapper1.5`
>
>    `make deb`
> 7. In your /usr/src directory, if all went well, you should find two brand new .deb package files starting with "ndiswrapper". Let's
>      install them.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SetupNdiswrapperHowto

Comment: I downloaded ndswrapper1.5.tar.gz. My device is listed here as "working" http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Belkin_F7D4101v1

Comment: Edited question.  Make sure the file name is ndiswrapper1.5.tar.gz, because I edited the original post to meet the file name.

Comment: BTW did you see your network receiver in Additional Drivers?